# Can I set eclipse to show a warning if RuntimeException is not handled?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, checked-exceptions

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    willItThrowException();
}

private static void willItThrowException() throws RuntimeException
{
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Is there any configuration of eclipse that can show a warning/error on uncaught runtime exception that is declared in method declaration but not catched in line of `willItThrowException();` ?

Comment: yes if eclipse shows a warning then its checked exception rather than a Runtime as JB said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, and I can't find one. Catching runtime exceptions is not always a good choice though. And you will get tons of warnings about catching `IllegalArgumentException` and `NullPointerException`. Runtime exceptions are usually meant not to be recoverable from.

Answer (score 3):

If it should generate a warning, then it means that your runtime exception should not be a runtime exception, but a checked exception. Runtime exceptions are not meant to be caught (in the general case). If they happen, it means that you have a bug in your program. Catching the exception won't fix the bug.